# Issue with looping in Java code

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

> Use a while loop to keep asking the user to enter the order of
>   numbers until the user does give two numbers in the right order (first
>   smaller than second

Hi! i'm a beginner in java and I have this code but I can't loop the "error" message. it just prints 2 times

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please type two numbers:");
        num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        num2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (num1 < num2) {
            int counter = num1;
            while (counter <= num2) {
                System.out.print(counter + " ");
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: the first number must be smaller than the second");
            System.out.print("Please type two numbers: ");
            num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
            num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps let people know which inputs you used?

Comment: what´s your actuall problem, for me it is working.

Comment: You need another loop, in which the `if/else` clause goes.

Comment: Hi, here's what I entered:   Please type two numbers:3 1
Error: the first number must be smaller than the second
Please type two numbers: 6 1

Comment: An easy solution is to put `while(num1 < num2) { // display error and ask again }` in the beginning and after that print the counter loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
int num1,num2;
while (num1>=num2) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type two numbers");
    System.out.printn("first number must be smaller than the second:)";
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int num1,num2;
while (num1>=num2) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type two numbers:");
    num1 = keyboard.nextInt();
    num2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(num1>=num2) {
         System.out.println("Error: First number must be smaller than the second.");
    }
}
```